# Eliminar una fila en fichero de java si cumple condición

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy haciendo una practica, en la que tengo que pedir el numero de departamento al usuario, y seguidamente eliminar la linea que contenga el ID del departamento. Hasta ahora solo he conseguido que me elimine la linea entera, pero no por numero de departamento si no por numero de linea. El fichero contiene la información de la siguiente manera:

```
1 | Policia | Barcelona
2 | Bomberos | Dublin
3 | Ejercito | Malaga
4 | Sanitarios | Madrid
7 | Sanitarios | Dublin
```

Este es mi código:

```
public static void borrarLinea() throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File("Departamentos.dat");
        File tempFile = new File("DepartamentosTemp.dat");
    
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lineToRemove;
        
        System.out.println("¿Que número de departamento deseas borrar?");
        lineToRemove = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();
        
        String currentLine;
        int count = 0;
    
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            if (count == lineToRemove) {
                continue;
            }
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        inputFile.delete();
        tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola estoy un poco oxidado en Java pero ahi va la ayuda intenta con esto:

```
public static void borrarLinea() throws IOException {
    File inputFile = new File("Departamentos.dat");
    File tempFile = new File("DepartamentosTemp.dat");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lineToRemove;
    
    System.out.println("¿Que número de departamento deseas borrar?");
    lineToRemove = entrada.nextInt();
    entrada.nextLine();
    
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] line_arr = currentLine.split("|");
        int num_linea = Integer.parseInt(line_arr[0]);
        if(num_linea == lineToRemove){
             continue;
        }else{
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));   
        }
        
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    inputFile.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo y le digo

Comment: Todo perfecto, me funciono correctamente muchísimas gracias :)